# Is there a simple way to exclude query instances that have a given model associated to it?

Tags: sequelize.js

So I know that you can specify sequelize to only return query instances that include a certain associate model via setting required to true:

```
Model.findAll({
        include: {
            model: AssociateModel,
            required: true
        }
```

My question revolves around this same mechanism, but with exclusion instead of inclusion.

I already managed to implement it, but in a somewhat roundabout way:

```
 Model.findAll({
        include: {
            model: AssociateModel,
            required: true
        }
    })
    .then(async result => {

        const ids_with_associate = await Promise.all(result.map(each => each.id))

        Model.findAll({
            where: {
                id: {
                    [Op.notIn]: ids_with_associate 
                }
            }
        })
```

and so I was wondering if there was a way to do it all within a single query. Something similar to:

```
Model.findAll({
        exclude: {
            model: AssociateModel
        }
```

I've tried looking it up online, but most of what I found was only regarding exclusion of attributes.